# Журнал звонков на galaxy

Tags: android, java, galaxy

Как можно вытащить список звонков из журнала звонков на устройствах самсунг, потому как андроид хранит только 500 звонков, а устройства самсунг хранят еще где-то эти звонки. Можно ли их как-то вытащить?

Comment: Как-то это не кошерно - иметь более 500 записей только на Galaxy. Можете, например, копировать записи о звонках в свою собственную базу, и регулярно обновлять журнал звонков, добавляя новые записи из тех 500, что дает вам система.    
То есть так:    
Приложение установлено - получили 500 последних, сохранили в свою базу.    
На завтра получили снова 500 последних, записали в базу те, которых там еще нет.    
Таким образом у вас буду все звонки с момента установки приложения + 500 звонков до этого момента.

Comment: сейчас так и делаю, но хочу сразу получить всю базу к примеру за пол года если они есть в галакси, а не собирать по кусочку, ведь наверное возможно получить такой список

Comment: Чтобы получить больше 500 записей, нужен либо РУТ доступ, либо ваше приложение должно находиться в системмном разделе.

Comment: @metalurgus да нет же, я видел приложения, которые при установке сразу же получают весь список звонков, хоть  5000, главное, чтобы они были в самсунговского журнала звонков.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если внимательно изучить [исходники](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.robolectric/android-all/5.0.0_r2-robolectric-0/android/provider/CallLog.java)  `android.provider.CallLog`, то видно, что действительно больше 500 записей в БД не хранится, основой является приватный метод:

```
private static Uri addEntryAndRemoveExpiredEntries(Context context, 
    Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
    final ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
    Uri result = resolver.insert(uri, values);
    resolver.delete(uri, "_id IN " + "(SELECT _id FROM calls ORDER BY " + DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER + " LIMIT -1 OFFSET 500)", null);
    return result;
}
```

То есть после вставки удаляется старая запись, если количество записей более 500.

Вижу такие варианты, как победить проблему:

1. В каком-то Galaxy захаркоденное число 500, видимо, можно задавать в настройках (я тоже как-то смутно помню, что в каком Galaxy так вроде и было) - сильно сомневаюсь, что в Galaxy провайдер CallLog переписан.
2. Заново собрать провайдер с увеличенным лимитом - скажем, 5000, и заменить стоковый провайдер на свой (нужен рут).
3. Поставить аппу, которая держит в своей БД историю звонков (таких, кстати, полно на маркете, например).
4. Написать кастомный `PhoneStateListener`, который после звонка будет сохранять историю звонка в свою/вашу БД (по сути, так и работают аппы, сохраняющие историю звонков).

Comment: @Barmaley можно было бы свою БД использовать и записывать туда, но это уже новые записи, к примеру, у меня в галакси есть звонки за последние полгода, 
а по запросу выдается только 500, интересует именно те записи, которые у пользователя хранятся в самсунговском журнале звонков.

Comment: Получи рут на свой аппарат, заходи в каталог `/data/data/[название пакета самсунговского логгера]/databases`, и будет тебе счастье

Comment: @Barmaley видел программы, которые брали и без рута весь самсунговский журнал  до последнего звонка, которые были, рут пользователю, к сожалению, не установишь

Answer (score 1):

Это точно, что 500, Вы считали?
И как определено, что хранится где-то ещё?

Вообще, если я правильно понимаю идеологию, то инфа о звонках хранится в журнале вызовов.
Доступ к нему через

```
getContentResolver().query(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,...
```

Возвращает Cursor.

Хотя, может быть, мои сведения устарели...
Буду сам рад узнать про другие места хранения!

Comment: да, мне об этом говорили, и видел код, сейчас не помню, где и какой класс именно, но вы можете вытащить курсор по вашему запросу, сам так вытаскиваю, и на любом телефоне вытаскивается только 500 или подсчитать, сколько там элементов в этом курсоре, их там вместе со всеми исходящими и входящими 500.

Answer (score 1):

Логи стоковые лежат тут:
`/data/data/com.sec.android.provider.logprovider/databases/log.db`
Их можно поковырять любым SQLite вьювером и убедиться, что звонков там максимум будет 500 штук. И столько же смс, как я понимаю. Это легко. Ищете первый звонок в базе, смотрите его дату, конвертируете в нормальный вид, а потом смело находите этот же звонок в стоковом дайлере. Он там тоже будет первым.

Comment: Я не понял, это /data/data/com.sec.android.provider.logprovider/databases/log.db БД содержит 500 звонков и в дайлере тоже 500 звонков, так в чем толк то от этой БД будет. Я хочу более 500 звонков